# What is an indoor Dock/Harbor called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

For more clarity, I am thinking about something more like a dock, but inside a building alongside or stretching out over a pond/ocean. There would be a wooden door which could be raised and lowered to allow boats entry, or closed to keep them within.

Is there a specific word for such a structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word you are looking for is ***boathouse*** (or *boat-house*).

> A building at the edge of a river, lake, etc., used to house boats.
>
> [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/298369?redirectedFrom=boathouse#eid)

A modern one from outside:

[image]
<sub>Source: www.mcmurrayconstruction.ca</sub>

From inside:

[image]
<sub>Source: earlferguson.ca</sub>

Comment: Is there a different synonym for it? I doubt it was called the same thing in the middle-ages, or even pre-middle ages for that matter.

Comment: @Krythic: In OED, earliest example is from 1625. Maybe there weren't enclosed docks before 1600's. Why would you need an older word? I don't think there is a synonym. There are terms like "private docks", "custom-built docks" etc. but _boathouse_ is the term used in maritime terminology and it is an official dictionary word.

Comment: Hmmmm... I needed it for description within a writing segment. I can describe the scene very fluidly; I was just looking for the actual name of the structure itself. However, I suppose I can side-step around having to use it. Boathouse just sounds really meh, you know?

Comment: You can check Wikipedia article also for more info and pictures: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boathouse

Comment: @ermanen- actually floating houses that look like a boat are called *houseboats*

Comment: @Jim: Ah, that is the right term, yes. But I saw some sources calling them boat houses also. Maybe that's why I mixed up the terms. And they are sometimes called float houses too. [deleted that comment]

Comment: A *boathouse* doesn't necessarily have to have a in indoor docking bay and/or boat ramp. It would, when built for bigger boats like the ones in the screenshot, but for rowing boathouses typically the rowers pick up the boat at the bank of the river and carry it inside. I don't know of a single word for the structure with the dock specifically

Comment: There's also the individual berth for each boat. You could call it "a covered berth" if you wanted. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/berth